# dump mdx query resultset into Excel

Tags: excel, mdx

How can I dump mdx query result set into excel?

Answer (score 1):

Excel has one or two ways to get OLAP data, but I don't think there is a way to write your own MDX in there. You could use "OPENROWSET" in SQL Analysis Services to save a CSV file of the results.

What OLAP provider are you using, and do you need to write your own MDX or not?